# Android - Embed youtube iframe in app

Tags: android, html, video

I need to embed a youtube video on my app, possibly showing the video while i am in the app and not using youtube app. I am able to do that using webview and the iframe embed thing in youtube video, and it works fine on 2 of my devices: one has Android 4.1.1, the other 4.2.
It doesen't work when i try on my phone with Android 2.3.4: it shows the thumbnail but when i click on it just remains a black space.
Maybe Android versions < 3.0 doesen't support HTML5 tags?
Sorry i am relatively new to this thing. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
    wbv = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wbv.setFocusable(true);
    wbv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    wbv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wbv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    wbv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    wbv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    wbv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wbv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    wbv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    wbv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wbv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    String html ="<html><body><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/ID\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
    String mime = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";        
    wbv.loadData(html, mime, encoding);
```

Answer (score 0):

as for me it works in following way:

```
final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
//settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+videoClip.youtubeId);
```

using aos 2.3.4 device. I also work if use your way, I mean IFrame:

```
final String sUrl =  "http://youtube.com/embed/"+videoClip.youtubeId;
final String html ="<html><body><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\""+sUrl+"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

however I confirm that both methods doesn't work on my froyo (2.2.2) aos device. It swows some blue chip for a seconds and thats all. It stays with black screen or frame.

Comment: indeed. Its better to use Google YouTube API for this.